# a question on Multi screen support: How to check in Java code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

In my android application, I have layout xml files in:

`layout/` , `layout-lan`

and

`layout-xlarge` , `layout-xlarge-lan` folders to support multiple screen sizes.

They are working fine, my application is running on different screen size tablets.

I have one table in my layout, `textview` components are inserted to the table on fly in Java code. In order to support multi screen size devices, I need to check if the device has large screen size (that's match `layout-xlarge`) or normal screen size(match `layout/`) in Java code (on fly) also to set the text size of `TextView`.

My question is how to check the screen size match `layout/` or `layout-xlarge` in Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your implementation correctly, nothing needs to be done programmatically.

If the TextViews you are adding on the fly are uniform, just make a separate resource that is this TextView. Then, you can make two different TextViews, specified for each layout. Android will choose at runtime which to use.

This way you can have two different textsizes specified in the two different textviews or create another resource.